# DOI support for hyperlinks

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

The [Digital Object Identifier](http://www.doi.org/) system is a way to identify content objects in digital networks. Among its advantages are that the DOI number is relatively short (compared to many URI on websites) and that they are stable (so much less likely to suffer from link rot).

A lot of academic resources (journal articles specifically) are most reliably linked to using their DOI number.

Minor feature request for the academic SE sites (like physics or maths): Can we support a link syntax for DOI numbers? I'm imagining something like `[DOI:1234.5678/901]` getting turned into what would be displayed by `[DOI 1234.5678/901](http://dx.doi.org/1234.5678/901)`?

Comment: Some advanced features for scientific citations would be great, [I asked for that a while ago on Skeptics](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/support-for-citations).

Comment: It would also be extremely cool if the software can automatically [dereference DOI numbers and parse author/title information](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6848/119). But that maybe asking for a bit much.

Comment: I don't think it's asking too much, I'd love to have this feature too. I'd prefer DOI to point to http://doai.io/ though.